# Passing all files of specific filetype in current and subdirectories

Tags: shell, directory, wildcards, recursive

I have constructed an elaborate 500+ character command with many arguments and switches to autosign multiple PDF documents.

I'm using JSignPDF and I'd like to use it's batch mode including the current directory and subdirectories.

The relevant part of the command I'm having trouble with is:

```
java -jar ../jsignpdf-1.4.3/JSignPdf.jar *.pdf -a
```

...which of course works great for all PDF files in the current directory. How can I make it so it picks up all .pdf files in all the subdirectories as well?

I've tried a few things which haven't worked... novice and not even worth mentioning...things like -r (obviously would-/did-n't work).

I'm wondering if this is a simple answer or in need of some awk magic, if that would even be valid. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `zsh` or `ksh93 -G`, you could do:

```
java -jar ../jsignpdf-1.4.3/JSignPdf.jar ./**/*.pdf -a
```

You could do the same with `fish` or `bash -O globstar`, but beware that those may traverse symlinks when descending the directory tree (fixed partly in `bash` 4.3, fully in 5.0 and above).

Otherwise, if the list of files is not too big, you could do:

```
find . -name '*.pdf' -exec sh -c '
  exec java -jar ../jsignpdf-1.4.3/JSignPdf.jar "$@" -a' sh {} +
```

But beware `find` may try to split the list and run several `sh` commands to try and overcome a limit on the command line size.

Comment: Both solutions worked beautifully! Thank you very much, very helpful.